# What is the meaning of "Vom Typus her streng"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I've read this word while searching the meaning of a preposition [here](http://www.linguee.de/deutsch-englisch/search?source=auto&query=Mir%20gegen%C3%BCber%20war)

But it was another confusing word to me, could you please explain, if you're exprerienced, what does it mean?

> **Vom Typus her streng,** aber mir gegenüber[...]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just means that the someone in question is not exactly of a casual breed, but rather of Victorian nature, stern in character.

Here’s two suggestions for an English translation:

> Of a stern type, but toward me… (he never raised the hand.)
>
> Strict of type, however towards me… (she’s quite approachable.)

Comment: "her" is an abbreviation of "woher?"

Comment: @Dragut No. Here *von .. her* means *from ..*, metaphorically *of*. On the other hand *woher* means *wherefrom / whence*.

Comment: "von X her" simply means "with respect to X", or "as regards X". It doesn't have a direct local sgnificance.